# Razor Code For Adding A Folder IN DNN 7

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

Has anyone ever created a new folder programmatically in DNN 7 using Razor c# code?

If so, can you provide an example...

For some reason, I'm unable to find the DNN 7 API anywhere on their site to assist.

Answer (score 0):

The core API help file is here:  http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/releases/view/134695

You will want to look at the FolderController class.  There is a FileController class for that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...

```
@using DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem;

@{
    IFolderInfo fi = FolderManager.Instance.AddFolder(portalId, folderPath);
}
```